# Flexbox wrapping nested rows without media query

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got four div's in a flexbox grid. I want them to wrap two at a time, like this:

```
+-----------------------+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  | 
+-----------------------+
+-----------+
|  1  |  2  |
+-----------+    THIS IS WHAT I WANT
|  3  |  4  |
+-----------+
+-----+
|  1  |
+-----+
|  2  |
+-----+
|  3  |
+-----+
|  4  |
+-----+
```

Now, this seems easy enough, just nest them inside new flex containers and apply flex-wrap, and give the cells some min-widths. However, this has the side-effect of making the middle view look like this:

```
+-----------+
|  1  |  3  |
+-----------+    NOT WHAT I WANT
|  2  |  4  |
+-----------+
```

Apparently, flexbox wants to first wrap the inner div's instead of considering them rows. In order to keep all of the other wrapping working, setting flex-basis (to e.g. 100%) for the nested div's is not an option. In order to keep everything dynamic (for instance adding a third cell to one of the rows), setting %-widths on the cells is not an option. And in order to avoid hard breakpoints and base wrapping on (dynamic) content width, I'd *really* like to avoid media queries.

**Can this be achieved with flexbox and without media queries?**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h02k8b9c/)

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 2px;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  flex: 1;
}

.cell {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: white;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** I know I can make the inner `.grid` not wrap at all, but what I really want is for all the cells to wrap below each other if space is super tight. (As in the first illustration.)

Comment: I updated my answer again, with some more explanation and a _best solution_ sample

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell the children-elements of `.grid .grid` to flow in a row:

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 2px;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  flex: 1;
}

.grid .grid {
  flex-flow: row; /* this is your fix */
}

.cell {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: white;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is probably good to explain why your solution works: when you declare `flex-flow: row`, the flex-wrap property is not declared in the shorthand. This means it will fallback to the default value, which is `nowrap`, and this prevents the nested grid's elements from wrapping to a new line.

Comment: This makes the inner grid `flex-wrap: initial` (=nowrap). That, in turn, means that the last (most narrow) view not wrap, i.e. I fixed one problem but created another.

Answer (score 1):

*Note, there is no specific Flexbox property that replace a media query, and no need either as media queries is perfect for this, better than any other available method or property.*

The trick here is to make the *inner* `grid`'s to wrap before the `cell`'s does. For that to happen they also need a minimum width, which is wider than the sum of the 2 `cell`'s.

The downside with that extra `min-width` is it will also affect the `cell`'s width on narrower screens

[Fiddle demo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/9h69ktfj/)

Stack snippet

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 2px;
}
.grid-outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.grid-inner {
  flex: 1;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  min-width: 210px;
}
.cell {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: white;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-outer">
  <div class="grid-inner">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-inner">
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

An option is to drop the Flexbox properties on the *outer* `grid` and set the *inner* `grid`'s to `inline-flex` and let the `cell`s grow with their content.

The downside with this is that the `cell`'s won't fill their parents width

[Fiddle demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/egw6827d/)

Stack snippet

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 2px;
}
.grid-outer {
  display: inline-block;
}
.grid-inner {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.cell {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: white;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-outer">
  <div class="grid-inner">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-inner">
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

The absolute best solution here is a combination of Flexbox and a media query, where one use the query to alter the *outer* `grid`'s flex direction to column...

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z4Ldeb1p/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 2px;
}
.grid-outer {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.grid-inner {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.cell {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: white;
  height: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid-outer {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-outer">
  <div class="grid-inner">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-inner">
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

...or drop the *inner* `grid`'s all together and change the `cell`'s  flex basis

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z4Ldeb1p/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 2px;
}
.grid-outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.cell {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: white;
  height: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .cell {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 4px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-outer">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having different definitions for the grids does the job. I redefined them as outer and inner grid.

EDIT: Added wrap for `.grid-inner` to cover width < 200px

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 2px;
}

.grid-outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  flex: 1;
  width: 230px; /* for demo purposes */
}

.grid-inner {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid green;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cell {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: white;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-outer">
  <div class="grid-inner">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-inner">
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Again, same problem as in Gerrit's proposed answer - the inner div's do not wrap at all, which is a problem when the width is <200px.

Comment: When <200px they now end as a single column.

Comment: That's almost great. :) With the caveat that the cells don't grow at all (except  in the last, single column case).